# Why could a new IIS7 install be showing blank pages for all files?

Tags: iis-7

I've tried to browse to .html, .png, .css, .txt files, but the page just comes up blank. I have tried browsing from other machines - same issue. Also (may be unrelated) there are no log files where I expect them to be: `C:\inetpub\logs` -- it only contains 1 empty `wmsvc` dir. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, you need to enable logs by installing the feature in "Turn windows features on or off" -- IIS > Health and Diagnostics

Comment: Also, any file I go to (exists or not) it shows a blank page, but says code 200 in the log. Weird...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This occurs when "Static Content" is not checked in add/remove features under the IIS node.

- Open Control Panel
- Click Programs and Features
- Click Turn Windows features on or off
- Check "Static Content" in 
    Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Common HTTP Features

[image: Windows Static Content Image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :-) Google + StackOverflow for the win!

Comment: thank you so much works like a charm